# How to convert a .nfo file to .fff file

Tags: java, xml

I have an infobase file and I want to convert it to HTML. I'm trying to convert this using the following library: https://github.com/imazen/folioxml it comes with a configuration file and part of it looks like this

```
myconfig:
....
 
  infobases:
    - id: info_a
      path: "files/info_a.FFF"
      aliases:
        - 'C:\files\info_a.NFO'
    - id: info_b
      path: "files/info_b.FFF"
      aliases:
        - 'C:\files\info_b.NFO
...
```

I was able to build and run the tool using the commands given

- mvn clean compile assembly:single -U -B -fae
- java -jar commandline/target/folioxml-commandline-jar-with- dependencies.jar -config core/folioxml/resources/test.yaml -export folio_help

But it fails with an error as it requires and FFF file as specified in the above config

After reading the Readme from the above repo they have specified some ways to export .NFO to .FFF, they recommend using Folio Views or Folio Builder but i was not able to find more information about these tools

Can someone please give more information about above tools like where to find them or tell me about any other way of exporting .NFO files to .FFF

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, "Folio Views" etc. was sold several times* and the last time I checked, it was owned by a company that doesn't actively sell it.

"Folio Builder" was a separately sold tool that was used to "pack" info-bases created by Folio Views and publish them to CD's. Folio Builder was quite expensive as I recall. That's the tool that created the FFF file (flat file).

Folio Views could create a shadow file, but I don't think it's the same thing as a flat file.

I think there was a free viewer for Folio Views infobases, you can ask Lilith River if she has it (and if it would help).  FYI: There's also an SDK/API called Folio Integrator that was even more expensive.

Maybe you could hunt down the current owners to see if they would be willing to help. When I tried to contact them they were unresponsive, maybe you'll have better luck.

*It was such a good product that it was sold to Microsoft, then Microsoft sold it.